# Change the focus and xAxis

Tags: highcharts

This is chart that I need:

[image: chart1]

This is my chart:

[image: chart2]

How to change the xAxis via time like in first chart and focus

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [time](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) xAxis type and define each point as array [x,y], where x is timestamp (time in miliseconds). Second solution is using [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval) and [pointStart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart) params.

The focus on element, can be realised `tooltip.refresh`.

```
chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[0]); //first point of first serie
```

Comment: i cant understand how to use this "refresh", can u show it in code?

Comment: See simple demo how to set focus / tooltip on the point (http://jsfiddle.net/vo2451pg/)